# Is it allowed to carry "a knife" or "a pepper spray" while traveling by road in the Schengen area as a woman?

Tags: legal, safety, schengen, hitchhiking, female-travellers

Can a solo female traveler carry a knife or pepper spray to be able defend of herself when she is on the road or when hitchhiking, or it is illegal?

Comment: I really doubt that being female is relevant to the answer.

Comment: There are still more female victims than male victims through solo traveling.

Comment: I don't deny it, but your question is whether it is legal.  I'll be shocked if there is a Schengen country where carrying such weapons is legal for one gender but illegal for the other.

Comment: I added it to know if there is a legal consideration for solo female travelers too. About your reaction toward Schengen area's rules I am innocent! :))

Comment: Isn't "cold weapons" to broad of a category? It'd would even include range weapons like example crossbows. No to mention swords, sabers, axes etc.

Comment: It has mentioned in the question, A knife to defend of yourself in front of some drunk hooligans or truck drivers who want to rape you in a car through hitchhiking!

Comment: If you're asking specifically about knifes, question title should be about knifes, not "cold weapons". Especially given that in many countries knifes are legal to carry *because* the are not considered weapons. Also gender is irrelevant to it's legality.

Comment: Thanks! I will edit it. about gender I answered it above.

Comment: gender is irrelevant as no country afaik (and certainly none in the Schengen area, Iran or Afghanistan my have such) has different laws for men and women.

Comment: Surely Iran doesn't have it. It is forbidden for all people in both sexes to carry any weapon and has been defined a pretty heavy fines for this matter. About Afghanistan I do not know as it is a very different country with Iran. I asked it to know if there is a different rule in Schengen area and has considered gender to decrease numbers of female raped victims through traveling alone.

Comment: @user37324 wasn't thinking exclusively about laws relevant to this question :) but good to know. And as to rape: the incidence of rape is quite low in most all Schengen countries. Sweden is a sad exception, and even there it's limited to certain cities (mostly Stockholm).

Comment: @jwenting Thanks dear! Personally I think there are equal dangers for solo female travelers whole around the world and surely the method of traveling and your safety considerations can effect it. I think Europe is one of safest regions for women but like some other places there are dangers for solo female hitchhikers. There is no special reason for me to point to Schengen areas in my question unless to know if these areas because of having active Feminists have also extra protective rules for women as solo travelers or not.

Comment: @user37324 the "protective rules for women" are effectively legislation that makes an accusation of sexual assault against someone a conviction, resulting in men so afraid to even come near women there's no way they're ever going to get bothered (side effect of course is that if a woman needs help, she won't get it because people are too scared of being arrested for even looking in her direction).

Comment: @jwenting: high rate of rape in Sweden is due very broad definition of rape there, which in other countries would constitute not rape, but sexual harassment.

Comment: @vartec in part, but also because they have a large subsection of the population that considers rape (in the strict definition) to not being a crime but their god given right to do to white females.

Comment: @jwenting: not unlike caliphates of France, Belgium, the Netherlands and Germany.

Comment: @vartec indeed, but there they're more actively prosecuted, given way less leeway and thus more afraid of the law still...

Comment: @jwenting: that would make great question for Skeptics.SE ;-)

Comment: @vartec Agree as there are all talks without evidences! :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This totally depends on the country, each country has different rules. Wikipedia has a page dedicated to [Knife legislation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knife_legislation). Check the countries you will visit before brining your knife with you.

Same thing goes for pepper spray, it is different from one country to another, again Wikipedia has a page dedicated to [pepper spray](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pepper_spray#Europe).

Stun guns are a bad choice as they are illegal in most European countries.

Comment: and check current information for each country, not just wikipedia. Laws and regulations change quickly, and may even be different from one city to the next or different at night as compared to daytime.

Comment: @jwenting Good idea for an answer, please post an answer with links to all official authorities in the European countries. That indeed will be a great answer.

Answer (score 9):

As @MeNoTalk already mentioned, the answer differs from country to country. I was expecting that the answer be that both are not allowed. Apparently even pepper spray is allowed in some EU countries.

Personally I would say both are really drastic measures to protect yourself and unnecessary. In general you would not need those to protect yourself.

In Europe self-defence is approached with proportionality. If some one would attack you without a knife or pepperspray and you would use either a knife or pepperspray to defend yourself, it could be that you end up being treated as the offender.

Those area's where you might be at risk, knife or pepperspray wouldn't help either. It is better to find out where the no-go area's are.

If you need to use a knife for any thing else then to protect your self, then it is allowed to carry a knife. If you are for example a scuba diver, you are allowed to cary double bladed knifes, BUT packed together with your diving gear in the back of your car.

Comment: Thanks! nice advices! I think it is better to forget hitchhiking! I like to travel safe not like a mindless traveler. I am adventurous and brave but not stupid! :)

Comment: It is correct, at least in Central Europe, that proportionality is the test.  It is even common to encounter urban legends along the lines of knife-only-against-knife.  However, the law enforcement does not work that way.  Proportionality does not mean that you must adopt the same methods and weapons as a potentional attacker to defend yourself.  Self defense generally needs to be higher intensity than the attack in order to be effective.  If the intensity of defense is blatantly higher even than what was necessary to avert the attack, such defense will fail the proportionality test.

Comment: @PersianCat - Europe is generally extremely safe to travel in, including hitchhiking.  I've been hitchhiking all across Europe as a teenager day and night, and never even thought of needing a weapon.  You won't find stats specific to hitchhikers, but comparing the frequency of specific crimes (per 100000 people) and adjusting your safety expectations for the society in general is quite easy.  Hitchhiking, you'll reach fewer places but more local people over the same travel time.  This may be good for you or an absurd waste of time, depending on why you travel.

Answer (score 2):

I answer about usage in France, not about legal aspects as I am not a lawyer.

Though urban life decreases the need for pocket knives, many people in rural areas still carry [Opinel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opinel_knife) or [Laguiole](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laguiole_knife) knives.

It is common also to bring a pocket knife when enjoying a picnic with [baguette](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baguette), [charcuterie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charcuterie) and [camembert](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camembert) (yes it is cliché, but yes it still belongs to french way of life).

Comment: Irrelevant but interesting! :))